# D3 Line altered after a zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a beginner in D3 and JavaScript development, i have succeed to generate a multi-line graph ( generated with an JS object) with interactivity. Every control work except that zoom alter line form.
I have tried to change data quantity and i don't know which part is guilty of that behavior. It appears after a given time, the line doesn't change and stay the same.

These pictures show this latter effect :

capture with the right line:

[image: capture with the right line]

capture with altered line:

[image: capture with altered line]

If anyone have any idea for resolve that.

[edit] i make another pass on my code and the problem seems linked to path update. i add these blocks of code if anyone see something wrong.

```
 function line_gen(num){
                graph['lineFunction'+num] = d3.line()
                .defined(function(d) {return !isNaN(d[graph.dict[num]]) })
                .x(function(d) { return graph.xScaleTemp(d[graph.dict[0]]);})
                .y(function(d) { return graph.yScaleTemp(d[(graph.dict[num])])})
                .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);
        }
```

```
 function updateData() {
                var t;
                function data_join(num){
                        if(!(graph.oldFdata.length)){
                                graph.dataGroup.select(".data-line"+graph.opt.name+num)
                                .transition()
                                // .duration(graph.spd_transition!=-1?graph.spd_transition:0)
                                .attr("d", graph['lineFunction'+num]((graph.Fdata)));
                        }else{
                                let update = graph.dataGroup.select(".data-line"+graph.opt.name+num)
                                .data(graph.Fdata);
                                update.enter()
                                .append("path")
                                .attr("d",graph['lineFunction'+num]);
                                update.exit().remove();

                                // graph.dataGroup.select(".data-line"+graph.opt.name+num)
                                // .transition()
                                // .duration(graph.spd_transition!=-1?graph.spd_transition:0)
                                // .attrTween('d',function(d){
                                //      var previous =d3.select(this).attr('d');
                                //      var current =graph['lineFunction'+num]((graph.Fdata));
                                //      return d3.interpolatePath(previous, current);
                                // });
                        }
                }
 
                for (var i = 1; i < graph["keys_list"].length; i++) {
                        if(graph[("lineFunction" + i)]==null){
                                indic_gen(i);
                                indicGrp(i);
                        }
                        data_join(i);
                }

                for (var i = 1; i < (Object.keys(graph.Fdata[0]).length); i++) {
                        /* update_tooltip(i); */
                        set_tooltip(i);
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem by rerendering it once more. Not the best solution but it's works.